# Python how to open a file without having the full path

Tags: python, json, path, filepath

so i want to read things from a file without having the full path, how can i do it?
My current code

```
import json

file1= 'C:\\Users\\klaus\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Script\\Mediamarktp.json'

with open(file1, 'r') as handle:
    json_out = json.load(handle)

profile_name = ['Profile1']

data = [x for x in json_out if x['profilename'] in profile_name]
email = (data[0]['email'])
password = (data[0]['password'])
website = (data[0]['website'])
precart = (data[0]['precart']=='True')
profilename1 = (data[0]['profilename1'])
proxy = (data[0]['proxy']=='True')

print(email)
print(password)
print(precart)
```

file1 is at the moment = 'C:\Users\klaus\OneDrive\Desktop\Script\Mediamarktp.json'
but i want my script to open it with just looking for = '\Script\Mediamarktp.json'
like

```
file1 = 'C:\\*\\Script\\Mediamarktp.json'
```

How can i do it?

Comment: It's not reasonable to expect your program to scan your entire file system looking for *one* path that your path suffix matches.

Answer (score 2):

Programs run in most operating systems with the notion of a "current working directory".  Thus, when code is asked to open a file it can either be a full path (like yours starting with "C:" for windows), or a "relative path" which depends on where the file is in relation to the current working directory.

If you're running your program from the command prompt, you can `cd` to the right parent directory (`C:\\Users\\klaus\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\`) and then access the file with just a relative path.  But it cannot start with a `\\`!

```py
file1= 'Script\\Mediamarktp.json'
```

Comment: Instead of `cd`, you could do the moral equivalent by having the script set the current working directory to the scripts parent dir. Then do file lookups using the relative path.

Comment: yep, thought of that.  You can also set the executable path in the windows file attributes too, I think.  (not a windows expert).

Comment: I think most people want to be able to reuse the script in other locations, so doing a `os.chdir()` leaves it only working in one set of files.

Comment: Yeah, really depends on how the script is meant to be used. If the file being opened is bundled with the app on installation then I would use the os.chdir trick, or use the script location and join the relative path to it. If the file is to be provided by the user, then just using the given cwd makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

This works nicely with the `glob` module.

```
import glob
myFiles = glob.glob(r'C:\**\Mediamarktp.json, , recursive=True)
```

If you don't use `recursive=True` it will not seach in sub folders.
But this will actually find all files with that name and search all directories on your drive. Thus it will be very slow, and it is not reasonable to do it like this. If you want to use `glob` restrict it to a more reasonable starting path.

An other way to do it would be setting the working directory to the path which contains the file

```
import os
os.chdir(myPath)
```

With this, you can open the file directly with its name. You can also use a relative path from the startup working directory of your script. If you are not sure what it is you can use

```
print("Current Working Directory " , os.getcwd())
```